# "load kernel" error on USB boot?

Tags: usb, live-usb

I followed these instructions:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

When I try to boot from bios into ubuntu it asks if I want to try without installing (yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do)

It then tells me a file is missing and I need to load the kernel first.

I see others have asked similar questions but no clear answers for a noob. I've never used any form of linux before.

Am I doing something wrong somewhere or do those instructions not work?

Thanks

Comment: I should add that I'm trying to load ubuntu 12.04.2 for AMD64.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when i went to use a livecd of backtrack, all i done was redoenload it and installed the image onto a new cd it started to work the, think it was just a problem with the download

Comment: Seriously? That's like 700 MB..*sigh*

Comment: This thing really doesn't like the return key... Ok, thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Thats what worked for me so hopefully will work for you, when wanting to go to new line press shift + enter